# Show Blinking Blue Dot and AnnotatationView for User Location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotationview

In addition to the blinking blue dot for user location, I would like to show a picture of the user at the user's location.  Is it possible to show an annotationView as well as the blinking blue dot?  Alternatively can one simply create an imageview and make it a subview of the blinkingblue dot?

This is the code I am working with but I can't achieve my objective:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
/* guard statement would result in showing a blinking blue dot
instead of an annotationview.  I have commented it out
guard mode !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
print("the delegate function is not allowed to show user annotation")
return nil
}
*/
//This shows the annotationView with custom image but I am not getting the blinking dot.
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png");
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.layer.frame.size.width / 2
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
annotationView.addSubview(imageView)
//      annotationView.superView.bringSubviewToFront(annotationView)

return annotationView
}
```

Comment: You would need to add "Blinking blue dot" functionality to your own annotation view

Comment: You could also add another annotation and update its position as the user's location changes

Comment: That makes sense.  I can add a separate annotation with the picture and them move it as needed.